# Is there a way to automatically include Entity Framework's data annotations in the xml help content?

Tags: entity-framework, documentation, ef-code-first, data-annotations, sandcastle

I have the following property in one of my POCO classes that are used to generate a Code First database:

```
''' <summary>
''' The surname of the player.
''' </summary>
''' <value></value>
''' <returns>A string containing the surname of the player.</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
<MaxLength(40)>
Public Property LastName As String
```

Is there some way to have the MaxLength data annotation automatically included in the documentation xml?